# Can i view per Database memory usage on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a test server with a number of databases on, which is filling with memory

i would like to analyse which databases are claiming the memory, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below query

```
 DECLARE @total_buffer INT;

SELECT @total_buffer = cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
WHERE RTRIM([object_name]) LIKE '%Buffer Manager'
AND counter_name = 'Database Pages';

;WITH src AS
(
SELECT 
database_id, db_buffer_pages = COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
--WHERE database_id BETWEEN 5 AND 32766
GROUP BY database_id
)
SELECT
[db_name] = CASE [database_id] WHEN 32767 
THEN 'Resource DB' 
ELSE DB_NAME([database_id]) END,
db_buffer_pages,
db_buffer_MB = db_buffer_pages / 128,
db_buffer_percent = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,3), 
db_buffer_pages * 100.0 / @total_buffer)
FROM src
ORDER BY db_buffer_MB DESC;
```

and you can go deeper querying by table level

USE AzureDevOps_Configuration;
GO

```
;WITH src AS
(
SELECT
[Object] = o.name,
[Type] = o.type_desc,
[Index] = COALESCE(i.name, ''),
[Index_Type] = i.type_desc,
p.[object_id],
p.index_id,
au.allocation_unit_id
FROM
sys.partitions AS p
INNER JOIN
sys.allocation_units AS au
ON p.hobt_id = au.container_id
INNER JOIN
sys.objects AS o
ON p.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
INNER JOIN
sys.indexes AS i
ON o.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
AND p.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE
au.[type] IN (1,2,3)
AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
)
SELECT
src.[Object],
src.[Type],
src.[Index],
src.Index_Type,
buffer_pages = COUNT_BIG(b.page_id),
buffer_mb = COUNT_BIG(b.page_id) / 128
FROM
src
INNER JOIN
sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors AS b
ON src.allocation_unit_id = b.allocation_unit_id
WHERE
b.database_id = DB_ID()
GROUP BY
src.[Object],
src.[Type],
src.[Index],
src.Index_Type
ORDER BY
buffer_pages DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just be aware that the suggested queries focuses on the Buffer Pool (cached data).

A database can have other types of memory usage as well, like exec plans (when database bound), working memory for queries, locks, etc. I don't know of a way to summarize those since many are, sort of indirect consequences of doing things inside a SQL Server, and some are not necessarily bound to a certain database.

Comment: And querying sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors can be expensive.